# How to print webelements in a table - Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

This code will go to a website, launch it, extract 2 web-elements(email, and ticket#) and print them successfully.

```
from audioop import add
from inspect import isframe
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


#Firefox Driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(r'C:\geckodriver-v0.32.0-win-aarch64\geckodriver.exe'))

#Launches Ticketing website
driver.get('WebsiteURl')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

#Switches to iFrame
iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="gsft_main"]')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

#Calls for value in row (Email and Ticket #)
Email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[8]")
Ticket = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]")

print(Ticket.text + " : " + Email.text)
```

**This is the output:**

TicketNumber001 : useremail@domain.com

The output works just as intended, but now I am looking to do this for the below columns utilizing the next 10 consecutive **XPaths**:

**tr[1]/td[3]

...

..

.

tr[10]/td[3]**

Which should look like this and I should be able to export that into a CSV to interact with a Powershell Script I have:

```
TicketNumber001 useremail@domain.com
...
..
.
TicketNumber010 useremail10@domain.com
```

I would appreciate your input, I'm a total newb with python and this is the first time using selenium.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

If there are no other extra data present for your table, you could use find_elements to fetch only the table data directly.

```
Tickets = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//table//td[3]")
```

This would give you an array of elements that you can manipulate.
You can iterate through the array to get the texts

```
for ticket in Tickets:
   print("Ticket:"+ ticket.text)
```

Assuming your email and Ticket are always equal

```
Emails = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//table//td[8]")
Tickets = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//table//td[3]")
for i in range(0, len(Tickets)-1):
   print(Tickets[i].text + " : " + Emails[i].text)
```

Comment: This gives me this error: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: The for loop should be len(Tickets)-1.
I have changed the answer, If it still persists, it could mean that your Tickets and Emails elements are not equal.